# trace kubernetes users activities in pods

Tags: logging, kubernetes, audit, cilium

I want to track users activities in a k8s cluster. for example I want to get k8s username of a user that executes a command in a pod. there is a tool named Tetragon. it can uses k8s api.
following log is a sample output from Tetragon on a k8s cluster:

```
    {
  "process_exec": {
    "process": {
      "exec_id": "bWluaWt1YmU6NzAyMDQ2ODIyNTEwNDg6MTE5MDk1MQ==",
      "pid": 1190951,
      "uid": 0,
      "cwd": "/",
      "binary": "/bin/sh",
      "arguments": "-c \"sleep 60m\"",
      "flags": "execve rootcwd clone",
      "start_time": "2023-07-22T13:37:01.382355175Z",
      "auid": 4294967295,
      "pod": {
        "namespace": "default",
        "name": "alpine-59dcb54bd-l7dtv",
        "container": {
          "id": "docker://767327faa6bc703188e434b74e80ed29f14973556b4411060674056cf9b305d6",
          "name": "alpine",
          "image": {
            "id": "docker-pullable://alpine@sha256:82d1e9d7ed48a7523bdebc18cf6290bdb97b82302a8a9c27d4fe885949ea94d1",
            "name": "alpine:latest"
          },
          "start_time": "2023-07-22T13:37:01Z",
          "pid": 1
        },
        "pod_labels": {
          "pod-template-hash": "59dcb54bd",
          "run": "alpine"
        }
      },
      "docker": "767327faa6bc703188e434b74e80ed2",
      "parent_exec_id": "bWluaWt1YmU6NzAyMDQ1NTgzNDYxOTA6MTE5MDkzMQ==",
      "refcnt": 1,
      "tid": 1190951
    },
    "parent": {
      "exec_id": "bWluaWt1YmU6NzAyMDQ1NTgzNDYxOTA6MTE5MDkzMQ==",
      "pid": 1190931,
      "uid": 0,
      "cwd": "/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/767327faa6bc703188e434b74e80ed29f14973556b4411060674056cf9b305d6",
      "binary": "/usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2",
      "arguments": "-namespace moby -id 767327faa6bc703188e434b74e80ed29f14973556b4411060674056cf9b305d6 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock",
      "flags": "execve clone",
      "start_time": "2023-07-22T13:37:01.258449828Z",
      "auid": 4294967295,
      "parent_exec_id": "bWluaWt1YmU6NzAyMDQ1NTAyNzk4MDM6MTE5MDkyNA==",
      "tid": 1190931
    }
  },
  "node_name": "minikube",
  "time": "2023-07-22T13:37:01.382358135Z"
}
```

Now I want to have k8s username of the user executed this commands. for example I want to have a field in a above json like:

```
username: minikube-user
```

does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a similar question to here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76699854/log-k8s-users-that-execute-commands-in-pods.

Essentially what you need to do is to correlate the k8s audit logs with the Tetragon logs about execution. Using the k8s metadata Tetragon adds to events (pod names, container ID, etc.) and the date you should be able to retrieve who performed the action at the k8s user level.

The part in the event you showed in example:

```json
"pod": {
  "namespace": "default",
  "name": "alpine-59dcb54bd-l7dtv",
  "container": {
    "id": "docker://767327faa6bc703188e434b74e80ed29f14973556b4411060674056cf9b305d6",
    "name": "alpine",
    "image": {
      "id": "docker-pullable://alpine@sha256:82d1e9d7ed48a7523bdebc18cf6290bdb97b82302a8a9c27d4fe885949ea94d1",
      "name": "alpine:latest"
    },
    "start_time": "2023-07-22T13:37:01Z",
    "pid": 1
  },
  "pod_labels": {
    "pod-template-hash": "59dcb54bd",
    "run": "alpine"
}
```

Should give you enough context to browse and correlate the k8s audit logs.